# Join conditions for two tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

When I have two columns with same name in two different tables but different data types.

Will I be able to join those two tables?

Comment: Give examples of your table structure, and what elements they may have in common

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

If you have:

```
TABLE_A

A_ID  NUMBER
DEPT  NUMBER
```

and

```
TABLE_B

B_ID  NUMBER
DEPT  VARCHAR2
```

If you were sure the values in TABLE_B.DEPT were numeric but stored as a string then you could:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE_A
  JOIN TABLE_B
    ON (TABLE_A.DEPT = TO_NUMBER(TABLE_B.DEPT));
```

or even

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE_A
  JOIN TABLE_B
    ON (TO_CHAR(TABLE_A.DEPT) = TABLE_B.DEPT);
```

The use of a function on one of the table's columns will defeat the use of any idex that column may have had on it, in which case you may want to consider a [function-based index](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/function-based-indexes.php) if the join is very important and the tables ar large.

FWIW, the column names don't have to be the same either, the names are irrelevent, it's the data that counts and whether it can manipulated into a format that can be matched against the columns you need to match it to.

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can join the tables. But if you want to address the column with the same name you have to specify the name of the table before the column name.

```
TABLE1 has columns A number, B number
TABLE2 has columns A number, B varchar2(10)
```

Then you would address the columns like TABLE1.B or TABLE2.B. Example

```
SELECT TABLE1.A, TABLE1.B, TABLE2.B
FROM TABLE1, TABLE2
WHERE TABLE1.A = TABLE2.A 
  AND TABLE1.B > 10
  AND TABLE2.B = 'FOO'
```

If table names are very long this can become complicated so you can define an equivalent for each table like this

```
SELECT x.A, x.B, y.B
FROM TABLE1 x, TABLE2 y
WHERE x.A = y.A 
  AND x.B > 10
  AND y.B = 'FOO'
```